# How to start "emacsformacosx" in terminal

Tags: macos, emacs

I am using MAC OX 10.6 , and install the emacs from here http://emacsformacosx.com/

I want to know how to start it in terminal, so my ecb can open current directory

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is actually quite easy, just run it from terminal like this:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw
```

the -nw option means to start emacs without the gui frame.

You can put the following in your shell (on my mac .zshenv) :

```
alias Emacs="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"
```

Then I just have two commands:

`Emacs` : for emacs version 24

`emacs` : for the apple version of emacs

Of course you can just alias the Emacs.app to emacs, but this allows me to customize the two differently - for instance Emacs 24 allows me to use list-packages and so forth. emacs 22 ignores most of this, so I can always revert to a 'bare metal' emacs if need be. Your usage may vary, but if you don't remember the arguments to emacs you can find them by doing this:

```
emacs --help
```

Some interesting ones:

```
Emacs.app --fullscreen
Emacs.app --line-spacing
Emacs.app --vertical-scroll-bars
```

More info here : http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Option-Index.html#Option-Index

Answer (score 10):

The answer from @Toymakerii is a good one, but you might also consider adding:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH
```

This way, you can use `emacsclient` to open files in an already-running Emacs instance:

```
emacsclient -t SOMEFILE   # Open SOMEFILE in a terminal frame
emacsclient -c SOMEFILE   # Open SOMEFILE in a new graphical frame
```

Depending on your Emacs version, you might need to put the following in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` (or `~/.emacs`, if you're old-fashioned):

```
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
  (server-start))
```

Answer (score 6):

In my `~/.profile` i have the following:

```
function emacs
{
    if [ -e "$@" ]
    then
        command open -a emacs "${@}"
    else
        touch "$@"
        command open -a emacs "${@}"
    fi
}
```

(The reason for having a function is to make it also work when the specified file does not yet exist when emacs is started)

Comment: Finally I can open emacs from terminal the proper way. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By default terminal will open /usr/bin/emacs on OS X.
You can change this behavior by changing what the "emacs" command will do. Open up ~/.profile and type the following:

```
alias emacs=open /Applications/Emacs.app
```

The next time you open a prompt this change will be active.  (or you can run "source ~/.profile")

Comment: The correct command is ``` alias emacs='open /Applications/Emacs.app' ```,  but I need to run "source ~/.profile" each time .

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is to simply do

```
open /Applications/Emacs.app --args foo
```

An alias would then be

```
alias emacs=open /Applications/Emacs.app --args "${@}"
```

or in csh/tcsh

```
alias emacs 'open /Applications/Emacs.app --args $1'
```

edit: this seems to need a full path to open the correct file... I don't know if this is a problem with Emacs.app or with tcsh