# Using Cask with Emacs.app

Tags: macos, emacs

Cask uses the built-in emacs on OSX which does not support the --script argument which Cask requires.  Is there some way to tell Cask to use the Emacs.app version?

I tried the solutions here: [How to start "emacsformacosx" in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149868/how-to-start-emacsformacosx-in-terminal)
but they did not help.

I finally just entered the command supplied at the bottom of the cask file:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -Q --script ~/.cask/cask-cli.el
```

This is not very elegant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell `cask` which Emacs executable to run, by exporting the environment variable `$EMACS`:

```
$ export EMACS=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
$ cask install
```

To avoid the repetitive process of setting this variable any time you want to use `cask`, you need to create a command line wrapper for Emacs.app.  It *must* be a proper executable on its own, and not merely a shell alias or function such as recommended at [How to start "emacsformacosx" in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149868/how-to-start-emacsformacosx-in-terminal), because neither aliases nor shell functions are available for subprocesses of a shell.

This is easily done by creating a file `/usr/local/bin/emacs`, with the following contents

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw "$@"
```

You will need root privileges to create this file, and you must mark it as executable afterwards:

```
$ sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/emacs
```

After this, you should be able to start Emacs.app from command line with `emacs`.  This is sufficient for Cask to pick up Emacs.app without setting `$EMACS`.

Alternatively, you may want to install Emacs with Homebrew, by

```
$ brew install emacs --cocoa --srgb --with-gnutls
$ brew linkapps
```

This automatically creates the command line wrapper, and has some other advantages, such as building with some additional libraries.

I strongly recommend the Homebrew approach.