# how to open emacs via OSX terminal

Tags: emacs

how do you open emacs for OSX? 
I have it downloaded in my Applications, but I don't know how to open it via my terminal (calling it "emacs test.cpp")..

I checked out some sites, but their solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to launch GUI Emacs from command line in OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171280/how-to-launch-gui-emacs-from-command-line-in-osx) or [How to start “emacsformacosx” in terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149868/how-to-start-emacsformacosx-in-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my .bashrc (or .zshrc) file.

```
alias emacs="open -a Emacs.app"
```

Answer (score 0):

ysakamoto's answer is correct.
I've taken it a step further, I'm using a shellscript using emacsclient to open a file in a running instance of Emacs, or launch a new one if there's none running. Alternatively, it just focuses Emacs/opens an empty session when I don't give it a file. [Take a look](https://github.com/crshd/bin/blob/master/e).